# Add mark down behaviour for datalist tag in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag for showing per-defined values on the page in my React application.

I am trying to add the markdown behavior for this datalist tag. So that I can provide suggestions to user while selecting the input from the dropdown.

For example, we have "Alabama, Alaska Arizona" countries and if user types **A** in the input box then we have to show **A** and then "*labama*" in a different color/shade (e.g., **A**`labama`).

For this I am referring this link http://afarkas.github.io/remote-list/demo/index.html

(Please check the first example from the given link.)

Here is my sample code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Find U.S. State" list="states-2" id="search-2" data-list='{"valueCompletion": true, "highlight": true}'> (long list example + mark-option behavior)
    <datalist id="states-2">
        <select>
            <option value="Alabama"></option>
            <option value="Alaska"></option>
            <option value="Arizona"></option>
            <option value="South Carolina"></option>
            <option value="Wisconsin"></option>
            <option value="Wyoming"></option>
        </select>
    </datalist>
```

I am able to auto populate the data but I am not able to provide markdown behavior.

Can any one provide me how to achieve given scenario in the React application Or is there any other way to achieve this functionality without using datalist tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a markdown behavior: you want to obtain an highlight effect.
With React you can use the good [react-highlight-words](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words).

A proof-of-concept example:

```
<option value="Alabama">
  <Highlighter
    highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
    searchWords={["A"]}
    autoEscape={true}
    textToHighlight="Alabama"/>
</option>
```

Then you need to play with CSS to obtain the bold/highlight effect.